# UIToolbar navigation between UItextfields

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i have this set up in my app
[image]

im trying to change between the textfield with the uibarbutton but it aint working

i have this code

```
-(void)setToolBar {
    UIToolbar* Toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

    Toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backwardIcon"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(prevTextField)],
                     [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"forwardIcon"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(nextTextField)], nil];
    [Toolbar sizeToFit];

    self.txtNombre.inputAccessoryView = Toolbar;
    self.txtAM.inputAccessoryView = Toolbar;
    self.txtAP.inputAccessoryView = Toolbar;
    self.txtEmail.inputAccessoryView = Toolbar;
    self.txtPass.inputAccessoryView = Toolbar;
}

    -(void)nextTextField {
    if(self.txtNombre){
        [self.txtNombre resignFirstResponder];
        [self.txtAP becomeFirstResponder];
    }else if(self.txtAP){
        [self.txtAP resignFirstResponder];
        [self.txtAM becomeFirstResponder];
    }else if(self.txtAM){
        [self.txtAM resignFirstResponder];
        [self.txtTel becomeFirstResponder];
    }else if(self.txtTel){
        [self.txtTel resignFirstResponder];
        [self.txtEmail becomeFirstResponder];
    }else if(self.txtEmail){
        [self.txtEmail resignFirstResponder];
        [self.txtPass becomeFirstResponder];
    }else{
        [self.txtPass resignFirstResponder];
    }
}

-(void)prevTextField{
    if(self.txtAP){
        [self.txtNombre becomeFirstResponder];
        [self.txtAP resignFirstResponder];
    }else if(self.txtAM){
        [self.txtAP becomeFirstResponder];
        [self.txtAM resignFirstResponder];
    }else if(self.txtTel){
        [self.txtAM becomeFirstResponder];
        [self.txtTel resignFirstResponder];
    }else if(self.txtEmail){
        [self.txtTel becomeFirstResponder];
        [self.txtEmail resignFirstResponder];
    }else if(self.txtPass){
        [self.txtEmail becomeFirstResponder];
        [self.txtPass resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

any ideas on what am i doing wrong since it just changes between the first two text fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of checking:

```
if(self.txtNombre)
```

you should be checking

```
if([self.txtNombre isFirstResponder])
```

For all textfields of course.
That is checking that your UITextField is currently being edited.

Also I would suggest, to make an NSArray from those UITextFields to make those methods looking nicer. Right now if you want to add more textfield, you need to copy paste a lot and rename properties - also easy to make mistake with that.

Comment: would you do it like this ?                                                                        NSArray textfields = @[self.txtNombre, self.txtAP, self.txtAM, self.txtTel, self.txtEmail, self.txtPass];                                                                               for (int i = 0; i < textfields.count; i++) {
        if([textfields[i] isFirstResponder]){
            [textfields[i] resignFirstResponder];
            [textfields[i+1] becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }

Comment: Yeah this way is nicer. It's easier to extend this functionality later on. Of course you need to handle edge cases - in this code it will crash for last one due to index out of array exception, so you should first check (if (i+1) < textfields.count) before you call becomeFirstResponder.